# Is it possible to allocate pre-tax money to a specific stock?

Tags: taxes, stocks

Are there any programs that let me put pre-tax money into an account where I can allocate money into stocks instead of funds?

Comment: In the US, traditional IRA, HSA, 401K, just to name a few.

Comment: @TTT: These may or may not let you pick individual stocks. Louis, you'll have to check that out yourself.

Comment: @keshlam - I agree. I meant there are no laws precluding you from using those vehicles to pick individual stocks, though certain banks may choose to not let you do it. In that case you can pick a different bank, except for employer sponsored plans- with those you are usually stuck with whomever your employer picks.

Comment: For company plans, it varies wildly. I work with 401k plans with BAML, and of the thousands of plans we manage, only a handful have the option for "self-directed brokerage" investments allowing their participants to invest in single stocks. Traditional IRAs would probably be the closest bet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether an investment is pre-tax is determined by the type of account (i.e., tax-advantaged vs ordinary taxable account), but whether you can invest in individual stocks is determined by the provider (i.e., the particular bank where you have the account).  These are orthogonal choices.  If you want to invest in individual stocks, you need to look for a bank that offers an IRA/401k/other tax-advantaged account *and* allows you to invest in individual stocks with it.  For example, [this page](https://www.fidelity.com/retirement-planning/learn-about-iras/ira-choosing-investments) suggests that Fidelity would let you do that.  Obviously you should look into various providers yourself to find one that offers the mix of features you want.